# How to merge APFS volumes because of low perfomance

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, high-sierra, apfs

Recently I bought a used MacBook Pro 15' with a i7 2,3 GHz processor, 16 GB RAM and 512 SSD total. But the machine runs very horribly. It's performance is nothing like you'd expect with this setup. I can't have Chrome opened with Sketch since it all gets very laggy and horrible. Normal interactions run very slowly, like opening launchpad, option+tab to a full size screen, and so on.

The machine came with a Boot Camp volume. I didn't erase it with native Boot Camp Assistant, but went to Disk Utility and erased it in it, after restoring the notebook to factory settings. But, I couldn't manage to merge the three volumes it had.

- Macintosh HD
- Home
- Container disk1

The Macintosh Volume is the one I use, where I install and keep all my stuff. The "Home" one is APFS and filled with 130 GB of I don't know what. The other one, Container disk1, APFS as well, has the same amount of storage as the other two but it's empty.

I've been searching ways to merge them all wondering it will improve my notebook perfomance a whole bunch. I have no idea whats lowering my perfomance and what is filling the other volume. I do not have another user too.

I am attaching some screen shots here, if it helps a thing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please open Terminal.app and enter: `sudo gpt -r show disk0` and `diskutil ap list` and add the output of both commands to your question by editing it!

Comment: So basically, you want to: 1) Boot to macOS Recovery from internet. 2) Restore `Container disk1` from `Container disk2`. 3) Remove volume `Home` from `Container disk1`. 4) Boot from `Container disk1`. 5) Remove `Container disk2`. You probably should first confirm `Macintosh SSD` is your startup disk. From the menu bar, select `➔About This Mac`. Post a comment to what startup disk is shown in the popup window.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Indeed, sir. Macintosh SSD is my startup disk.

Comment: @DaniloLeal I cannot see any reason why this should be the cause of your performance problems. I think you might be going down the wrong path here. Have you tried to look at Activity Monitor and other tools to figure out what is using your CPU-time, how much memory is being used, and if there's massive I/O waits somewhere?

Comment: To further reinforce with @jksoegaard stated, there's no reason that multiple partitions should cause performance issues - it only boots from one partition at a time.  Have you tried [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.  Since you bought it used, I would be suspect of any problems experienced out of the box.

Comment: @jksoegaard kernel_task on the Activity Monitor is one thing that is always taking most memory. But, it's not a significant amount, only like 1GB or so. Is this too much? But on the CPU side of things, it does takes a lot, plus Windows Server.

Comment: @DaniloLeal No, that is not too much. What do you mean Windows Server? - Are you running Windows Server on it as well?

Comment: @jksoegaard No, I am not! But not sure why this is popping up there.

Comment: @DaniloLeal Ah... you're just not reading it right. You're talking about "WindowServer", not "Windows Server". Please include screenshots so that we can see exact information.

Comment: @jksoegaard sorry man, you're right. here are some screen shots of activity monitor right now. my computer is very bad at this very moment, alt tabbing is laging it all, even clicking in another chrome tabs http://ibb.co/jdJXqH / http://ibb.co/eccgjc

Comment: Those screenshots show no problems at all. If what you describe is correct, have your Mac taken in for a check up of the hardware. Also you could try running the built-in hardware check yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The partitions should have nothing to do with performance issues, I have the same computer and three partitions on the disk as well. I would run the hardware test that is mentioned above and you can also try resetting the NVRAM (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and you can try resetting the SMC as well (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295). Apple recommends resetting the NVRAM/PRAM first and then resetting the SMC. I normally find resetting the SMC to do the trick though. Also, don’t worry, neither of these will hurt your computer if they do not work.